# Why I receive an extra space in my hub_challenge? (Instagram Subscribe)

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I tried to make an Instagram Subscription by cURL method in PHP. Every looks fine but I receive this weird response:

```
{"meta": {
"code": 400, 
"error_type": "APISubscriptionError", 
"error_message": "Challenge verification failed. 
Sent \"361de01a08534930bd9af728a62ca8cd\", 
received \"b' 361de01a08534930bd9af728a62ca8cd'\"."}}
```

I spend all my day trying to decipher this but I have no idea what's happened here. 
Thanks to everyone!

**subscribe.php**

```
<?php
require_once "pass.php"; //Here I have all pass and ids

$client_id = '$insta->$client_id';
$client_secret = '$insta->$client_secret';
$object = 'user';
$object_id = 'self';
$aspect = 'media';
$verify_token='asd';
$callback_url = 'https://myURL/InstaTest/callback.php';

$attachment =  array(
'client_id' => $client_id,
'client_secret' => $client_secret,
'object' => $object,
'object_id' => $object_id,
'aspect' => $aspect,
'verify_token' => $verify_token,
'callback_url'=>$callback_url
);

$url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  //to suppress the curl output 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

print_r($result);


?>
```

**callback.php**

```
 <?php
if (isset ($_GET['hub_challenge'])){
    echo $_GET['hub_challenge'];
}

//This is an update
else {

    $myString = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $answer = json_decode($myString);
    echo $answer;
}
?>
```